# Karma/jasmine/pact-js example using requirejs

Tags: requirejs, pact

I am working on the [karma/jasmine example](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js/tree/master/karma/jasmine). It works fine as-is. I need to get it to work with requirejs. When I introduce requirejs and convert the client and client-spec classes to AMDs, I start getting this error:

PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0) Client sayHello should say hello FAILED
        TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'Pact') in js/client-spec.js (line 11)
        js/client-spec.js:11:28

To see the problem, you can look at [my example project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ckfazuegdi1d5qd/PactTest.zip?dl=0). To run it:

1. Extract the zip file in my example project above
2. From the PactTest directory, run: 
   npm install
3. After that is finished, run: 
   npm run test:client

Cheers,
Mike

Comment: I'm not certain you're using requirejs properly and I'm fairly sure the issues you're seeing is because the configuration hasn't been set properly for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi, Do you have package.json you used for it?

Comment: @user2451016, the package.json is in the example project linked above.

Comment: Mike Hi, Thanks but can not access it, due to firewall. Do you have gist / github? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the module name to "Pact" instead of "pact-web". It seems that requirejs can't find the matching module name.

In `client-spec.js` change the `define` to:

```
define(['client', 'Pact'], function (example, Pact) {
```

In `test-main.js` update the config as follows:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '/base',
    paths: {
        // 'pact-web': 'node_modules/pact-web/pact-web', <-- not this
        'Pact': 'node_modules/pact-web/pact-web',
        'client': 'js/client'
    },
    deps: allTestFiles,
    callback: window.__karma__.start
})
```

Admittedly, I don't fully understand the ins and outs of RequireJS, but this does work.

I've updated the [Pact documentation](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js#using-pact-with-requirejs) to include a note on this.

Here is a link to an updated Gist for future reference: https://gist.github.com/mefellows/15c9fcb052c2aa9d8951f91d48d6da54